# how do I add spaces to os.system commands

Tags: python

I am trying to add some spaces on the start of each line from os.system commands

```
example

os.system('pip install pyinstaller')
```

and then I get this

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (5.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32"->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

but I want to add some spaces on each line for visuals so it fits in with the rest
I have looked it up many times and I have searched for hours but I can't find it pls help

Comment: Please tell us (in code) what you've already tried.

Comment: `os.system()` does not give you any control whatsoever over the output of the command - it's going directly to your terminal, bypassing Python completely.  Use one of the functions in the `subprocess` module instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output to `sed` in the command:

```
os.system("pip install pyinstaller | sed 's/^/  /'")
```

Although as a comment mentioned, a better solution would be to use `subprocess.Popen()`. Then you can read the output of the command, transform it in any way you want, and then write the modified output to the terminal.